# tinymce tabulator indentation

Tags: javascript, tinymce, text-editor, rich-text-editor

is there any way to get tinyMCE to handle the pressing of the tab-key properly? currently I am using the nonbreaking plugin, but that only inserts three nbsp and that's not enough. I was thinking something along the lines of tab inserting a span around the text, but I am unable to find any plugin like that. I have also tried overwriting the "tab" button, but I am unable to figure out what to do after that has been done.

Comment: +1 this is a very good question

Answer (score 0):

Run over this problem last year.
Problem here is that browsers remove tabs and other space characters at the beginning and end of paragraphs (in the editor too). Unfortunatly, there is no way to get a 100%-functional tab in a web editor. But it is possible to get something similar except that the length of that "tab" is fixed.

Our solution to this is to replace tabs with a [white space character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29#Table_of_spaces) of a certain size when loaded from databse.
On insertion of a tab we insert the space character. 
And when the content gets written back to the database we replace the character with a real tab.

Answer (score 0):

for me tab should be working like Indent/Outdent, i found a plugin for this

http://davejamesmiller.com/snippets/wordpress-keyboard-shortcuts-to-indentoutdent-and-format-as-code-in-tinymce